# How to run an SSL cert on localhost for Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

Running Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 4.2.10 and using Thin server on development.

My app is using SSL on Heroku. Need to run SSL on my local Mac.

I followed this tutorial.

https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/enable-ssl-for-rails-development-environment-two-minutes

Here is my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin start -p 3001 -e development --ssl --ssl-verify --ssl-key-file server.key --ssl-cert-file server.crt
```

Here is the error I am received in trace

```
Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `parse'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run_machine'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    /Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    script/rails:6:in `require'
    script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

UPDATE:

Though my procfile contains information about cert. I manually start my THIN rails server via terminal like this.

```
bundle exec rails server thin start -p 3001 -e development
```

So not sure if it is using the Procfile?

UPDATE 2 ========

Tried to use `bundle exec thin start -p 3001 --ssl`
Had force_ssl set to false

Server starts

```
jn$ bundle exec thin start -p 3001 --ssl
/Users/jn/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:103: warning: epoll is not supported on this platform
Using rack adapter
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3001, CTRL+C to stop
```

Try to hit https://localhost:3001 and server stops with error

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Encryption not available on this event-machine
Abort trap: 6
```

=====  UPDATE 3: ======

Tried Puma.io failed same issue (cant establish a secure connection).
Tried Puma-dev failed to even recognize .dev URl 
Tried manually adding cert and key again same issue (cant establish a secure connection).

App loads our app signin form at http://localhost:3000. As soon as I log in the app loads the correct user account page using http then about 1 second later page is redireted to the same user account page but https which says 'can't establish a secure connection'. Have no idea why the browser is forcing me to https? Nothing in the app is set to https that I can "Find/Replace".

Generated a new secret_key as think it was short 20 characters in stead of 30. Pasted into secret_key.rb restarted server. Same ssl issue.

Comment: are you invoking `"https://localhost"`?

Comment: I have tried both. If I used http Chrome forces it to https. Https directly does not work either.

Comment: What's going on with the hyphens and spaces in your command? Are you sure it's `– ssl – ssl-key-file ~/.ssl/localhost.key – ssl-cert- file ~/.ssl/localhost.crt` and not `--ssl --ssl-key-file ~/.ssl/localhost.key --ssl-cert-file ~/.ssl/localhost.crt`?

Comment: Made the suggested change and still the same issue.

Comment: I recommend following a different guide or very carefully examining every single step in the guide you linked to because it has totally mangled the spaces and hyphens and I wouldn't be surprised if you have other copy/paste issues.

Comment: Tried a different one and still the same issue.  https://makandracards.com/makandra/15903-using-thin-for-development-with-ssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the app to 2.3.1 which got puma-dev to work. 
Removed `config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true` which was throwing an error.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [puma-dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev) for local development. It makes HTTPS available without a hassle.

> Puma-dev automatically makes the apps available via SSL as well. When you first run puma-dev, it will have likely caused a dialog to appear to put in your password. What happened there was puma-dev generates its own CA certification that is stored in ~/Library/Application Support/io.puma.dev/cert.pem.

Comment: Puma does NOT work at all. Followed this https://stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/ruby-on-rails/switching-pow-puma-rails-development/ and get Unable to Connect when hitting https://statrubytwotwo.dev/ or http://statrubytwotwo.dev/

Comment: Run `puma-dev -d dev` to handle `.dev` domains, but it's better to use `.test` or `.localhost` domains since Chrome & Firefox now force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS.

Comment: Also you can see development logs to see what happened. Maybe there is an error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Based on your last comment.  You need to start your local server either with

```
foreman start -f Procfile
```

Or with

```
bundle exec thin start -p 3001 --ssl –-ssl-key-file ~/.ssl/localhost.key –-ssl-cert-file ~/.ssl/localhost.crt
```

However this Profile won't work in production.  You might want to use an alternate `Procfile-dev` file in development

ORIGINAL:

In Procfile try hard coding the port use 3001 for ssl

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p 3001 --ssl –-ssl-key-file ~/.ssl/localhost.key –-ssl-cert-file ~/.ssl/localhost.crt
```

UPDATE 2: You shouldn't need a cert at all for local dev, you should be able to allow access via Chrome

```
bundle exec thin start -p 3001 --ssl  #this should work without any other arguments
```

Then you need to pass the port into the browser

```
https://localhost:3001
```

You might also try to comment out this in application.rb

```
#config.force_ssl = true
```

That should only be set in production.rb

As to why you can't install `gem install foreman` I'm not sure why you can't, it sounds like some kind of network problem on your machine, do you have a firewall blocking?

Comment: Tried that same issue. Want to be sure I am using the procfile, but manually starting server via terminal "bundle exec rails server -e development"

Comment: What do you mean be sure you're using Profile?  Are you using foreman?

Comment: See updated answer. Profile is not used just by being there.  Locally you  need to run `gem install foreman` and then see my updated answer.

Comment: gem install forman fails. ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH)
    No route to host - sendto(2)

Comment: jn$ gem install foreman
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH)
    No route to host - sendto(2)

Comment: Also use your bundle exec command in terminal says --ssl is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and follow these steps

1. openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -keyout
   localhost.key -out localhost.crt
2. sudo nano  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localhost.crt and copy text from
   gernate file localhost.crt save
3. sudo update-ca-certificates
4. add gem "thin"
5. for run sever "thin start --ssl --ssl-key-file localhost.key --ssl-cert-file localhost.crt"

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all youll need to have easy-rsa

   ```
   sudo apt install easy-rsa
   ```
2. Become root

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
3. Go to the easy-rsa folder

   ```
   cd /usr/share/easy-rsa
   ```
4. Copy example config file

   ```
   cp vars.example vars
   ```
5. Open vars in your preferred text editor

   ```
   vi vars
   ```
6. Uncomment these rows and fill in your values (CZ, Praha, Org. name...)

   ```
   set_var EASYRSA_REQ_COUNTRY "CZ"
   set_var EASYRSA_REQ_PROVINCE "Praha"
   set_var EASYRSA_REQ_CITY "Praha"
   set_var EASYRSA_REQ_ORG "Intel"
   set_var EASYRSA_REQ_EMAIL "ca@localhost"
   set_var EASYRSA_REQ_OU "Unit"
   ```
7. Generate cert

   ```
   ./easyrsa init-pki (type yes if required)
   ./easyrsa build-ca (type password 2times, then type your server name)
   ```
8. Copy cert to your home

   ```
   cp /usr/share/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt ~ubuntu20/ (NOTE that ubuntu20 is my home, your will be different)
   sudo chmod +r ca.crt (run this command from user terminal (no root), it changes permissions from root to user.)
   ```
9. Next command run from "/usr/share/easy-rsa" path. !! IMPORTANT !! local.max.support is my server name, choose your own

   ```
    ./easyrsa build-server-full local.max.support (type new password (2times) and then password we typed before)
   ```
10. Redirect from port 3000 to 443 (HTTPS)

    ```
    sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
    ```
11. Check if we make it correctly

    ```
    vi /etc/hosts

    127.0.0.1 localhost local.max.support (if your see this (with your server name), its probably correct.)
    ```

    Another test:

    ```
    ping local.max.support (If its responding GOOD JOB!)
    ```
12. Import ca.crt from your home to the browser as a Authority. In Chrome: Settings -> privacy and security -> Security -> Manage certificates -> Authorities -> Import
13. Move cert and key to your project `/config`

    ```
    cd /usr/share/easy-rsa/pki/certs_by_serial (here is your cert, rename it from "hash".pem to yourServerName.crt (In my case local.max.support.crt))

    cp local.max.support.crt ~ubuntu20/Desktop/centraldb-portal/config (COPY that file to your project /config)

    cd /usr/share/easy-rsa/pki/private (here is your key)
    cp local.max.support.key ~ubuntu20/Desktop/centraldb-portal/config (move key to your project)
    ```
14. Change permissions from root to user (Open new user terminal)

    ```
    cd /Desktop/centraldb-portal/config (Go to your project config folder)
    sudo chmod +r local.max.support.crt (Change permissions)
    sudo chmod +r local.max.support.key (Change permissions)
    ```
15. Run your HTTPS server

    ```
    bin/dev -b "ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?cert=./config/local.max.support.crt&key=./config/local.max.support.key"(type cert password), (don't forget to edit your .key, .crt files names)
    ```